# Unexpected gap between Text lines in jetpack compose

Tags: android, text, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I am getting too much gap between text lines in Text composable whenever it enters in new line
Here is the code. I am using material 3 1.1.2 and jetpack compose version 1.5.1

```
@Composable
fun Product(productItem: ProductItem) {
    Column(
        modifier=Modifier.clickable {  },
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(1.sdp)
    ) {
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart) {
            AsyncImage(
                model = productItem.image,
                contentDescription = "",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.height(50.sdp)
            )
            ElevatedCard(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 2.sdp, bottom = 2.sdp),
                elevation = CardDefaults.elevatedCardElevation(defaultElevation = 3.sdp),
                shape = AbsoluteRoundedCornerShape(3.sdp),
                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = productItem.price,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(2.sdp),
                    fontSize = 6.ssp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(500)
                )
            }
        }
        Text(
            text = productItem.name,
            fontSize = 6.ssp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight(500)
        )
        Text(
            text = productItem.sku,
            fontSize = 5.ssp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight(400)
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the image with issue
[image]

The lines are expected to be close as I haven given any padding or anything. It just happens when new line starts.

Comment: You have specified a gap in `Arrangement.spacedBy`. Maybe try removing that?

Comment: I has faced this issue. solve by assigning the ```lineHeight``` to the text. in M3 there is a default setting which makes it look like this.

Comment: @gtxtreme Well the spacedBy give space to it's components and is not supposed to give space between lines of same Text composable, although I tried it, didn't worked

Comment: @ChiragThummar Thank you man, It worked, it is really pain in the aas. Is it a bug or something? It is not supposed to be like this!!

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed by setting `lineHeight` same as text size. Thank you @ChiragThummar for your comment!!